# iOS Notification push with battery level

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, battery

I'm a student developing an iOS app, and I want to display a simple banner notification on the device, when a specific battery level is reached.

I found some interesting things (http://www.appcoda.com/local-notifications-ios8/) with local notifications, but I don't get a part of the implementation...

When doing the notification setup, we have to write this :

```
localNotification.fireDate = datePicker.date
```

But I guess that there is an other way than a precise date and time to set an activation event for the notification, and so I want to do it by checking the battery level.

When some people write this :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(...
```

I can't find a complete code with the next part of the execution, because I guess there is a part where we add buttons for the pop-up.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it short: **You can't.**
Monitoring battery usage is possible, but as soon as your app is suspended by iOS (because the user locked the phone or put your app in background), you won't be able to execute any code.
You can use Background Modes to prevent iOS from suspending your app, but if you don't have a feature that requires those background modes, your app will be rejected by Apple.

About local notifications: the only way to trigger them is with a date. You can't hook them up to some event.

Comment: In fact, I'm using the location feature to keep my app in background. If I'm right, NSNotificationCenter is not displaying any notification banner, it's only a listener for a callback ? So if it's the case, I only have to do an addObserver for battery level changes and after I trigger a local notification to the current date for displaying it now ?

Comment: Yeah... But if your app use the location as a trick to keep running, without any genuine feature actually needing persistent location updates, Apple will reject your app. And you will drain the user's battery too (that would be odd for an app that monitors the battery right ?)

Comment: The app gotta send the location of users when their batteries reach a low level, I wonder if Apple is tight with that...

Comment: It will never go through Apple's validation. Persistent location updates are VERY intrusive and VERY battery consuming. You should re-consider. Apple has very restrictive guidelines for a reason, and they don't like at all when you try to go around those restrictions.

Comment: You're totally right, I think that my society has to reconsider it. Thanks for your help